# Error In Use Smart Effect component?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, effects

I use smart effect component in delphi. i use animationform & animationlist, i run it but when i close application it get error like image below,,, how to solve that? or is there any component to get transtiton/animation effect like smart effect?

help me, thank's,,,,

[image: Error When Closed]
[image]

[image: SEAnimationList Property]

Comment: The debugger is your friend, what she says?

Comment: yeah, I can read it but I don't understand, so what should I do??

Comment: Is it a commercial component? Ask the component author, for help. Is it open source? Well, step trough the component code and you will figure out what's missing on your configuration or what's the bug in the component, and fix it. Or ask someone in the community to help you (maybe the component have a forum of assiduous users). IMHO this question is too localized for StackOverflow and I'm voting to close it.

Comment: What is the `FShowAnimation` object ? Did you create an instance of it ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the output you provide we can see that the debugger has broken at this line:

```
while time < FShowAnimation.Time do
```

and your error message is

```
Access violation .... Read of address 00000034
```

Attempting to read an address so close to zero is what happens when you try to read a field from an object reference that points to `nil`. From this we can conclude that `FShowAnimation` has not been instantiated.

The solution is to make sure that `FShowAnimation` is instantiated.